# Dynamically get Object's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I dynamiclly get an attribute value for an activerecord object?

for example I have a variable named `attr_name`.
I want to do something like this:

```
person = Person.find(1)
attr_name = "address"
address = person.<function_name>(attr_name)
```

which `function_name` can be used ?

Answer (score 35):

Either use `person.attributes[attr_name]` or `person.read_attribute(att_name)`, or even shorter then this is `person[attr_name]`.

Comment: This is the safest and correct way. Note that this will only work for attributes, not other methods, or associations.

Comment: Unable to get attributes or methods with the `object[symbol or string]` syntax. Create a simple class and make some variable or method publicly accessible with the dot syntax first to see it works, then try to access it via symbol or string.. no worky.

Comment: ```
class Foo

  def initialize
    @foo = 'foo name'
    @bar = 'bar name'
  end

  def foo
    @foo
  end

end

foo = Foo.new
foo[:foo]
```

Comment: @NickRes that is activerecord only.

Answer (score 5):

[send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) is the method you're looking for.

Comment: depending where the function names comes from, this could be quite dangerous, so I would not do that

Comment: If you're just getting the attribute value dynamically then I would definitely use something like `[]` or `attributes[]` or `read_attribute`. It's clearer and less dangerous. But, to do really dynamic things, you'll need `send`.

Answer (score 2):

If doing this using `send`

```
address = person.send("function_name" + "attr_name")
```

Comment: If you're just getting the attribute value dynamically then I would definitely use something like `[]` or `attributes[]` or `read_attribute`. It's clearer and less dangerous. But, to do really dynamic things, you'll need `send`.